# Android sepolicy in Android N

Tags: android

One of the native daemons in Android has stopped working in Android N version due to sepolicy failures. Adding the below policy fixes it:

```
allow my_daemon toolbox_exec:file { read open getattr execute execute_no_trans };
```

This policy was recommended by audit2allow tool. There is not much information available online to understand what exactly this toolbox_exec is, and why all those permissions are required for the daemon.

Kindly help.